# Log all messages from a channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to fetch all messages from a channel, then log the content from those messages, is there a way to do this?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
const fetched = await client.channels.get("505989241600213012")
.fetchMessages({limit: 1})
.then(message => console.log(`[${message.author.name}]${message.content}`));
```

This is the result I get:
`Undefined`,
and `[${message.author.name}]`
 It doesn't even return anything, since you can't read anything from `undefined`.

Comment: What does the above code output? Are there any errors?

Comment: Undefined, and [${message.author.name}] doesn't even return anything, since you cant read anything from undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchMessages`will always return a Collection, even if you use `limit: 1`. So, if you want to access the first element of the Collection you need

```js
const fetched = await client.channels.get("505989241600213012")
.fetchMessages({limit: 1})
.then(messages => console.log(`[${messages.first().author.name}]${messages.first().content}`));
```

If you plan to save the messages outside of Discord you might want to consider to use [cleanContent](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=cleanContent). It's also not good practise to combine `await` and `then`. Probably a good idea that you choose one.

Comment: Is there a way to go over the 100 messages limit?

Comment: No, 100 messages is the limit